# How do I create more makers with more unique popups?

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

I am attempting to create a map with Leaflet that has unique files attached to different popups. I can generate a marker with the popups I want but I can not generate a second marker with different popups.

Here is my code, how do I create more markers with more unique popups?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Bowers First Web Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
#mapid {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1200px;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapid"></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([39.74739, -106], 4);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
}).addTo(map);

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 100;

        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
}
    
    var marker = L.marker([31.665779, -103.061603]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup('Well Name: <a href="file:///C:/Users/funny/Desktop/Work/OBrien.pdf" class="speciallink">Mud Log</a>' + 
    '</br>' + 'Data: <a href="file:///C:/Users/funny/Desktop/Rig/PermianBasin_Wolfcamp_EIAReport_Oct2018.pdf" class="speciallink">Prog</a>' +
    '</br>' + 'Data: <a href="file:///C:/Users/funny/Desktop/Rig/PermianBasin_Wolfcamp_EIAReport_Oct2018.pdf" class="speciallink">Geosteer</a>');
    $('click', '.speciallink', function() {
    alert('Clicked the Link');
});

//Example of what I want to do but new marker does not show up//

var marker = L.marker([31.165779, -103.161603]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup('Well Name: <a href="new.pdf" class="speciallink">Mud Log</a>' + 
    '</br>' + 'Data: <a href="diff.pdf" class="speciallink">Prog</a>' +
    '</br>' + 'Data: <a href="diff.pdf" class="speciallink">Geosteer</a>');
    $('click', '.speciallink', function() {
    alert('Clicked the Link');
});
    
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems you want to have several markers at the exact same place. How do you expect them to be displayed? In your case both markers are added to the map, but one covers the other. For the solution you need something called "marker clusters", see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Comment: I want the markers in different locations biased on lat and long, as you can see one is var marker = L.marker([31.665779, -103.061603]).addTo(map); the second is var marker = L.marker([31.165779, -103.161603]).addTo(map);

Comment: Ups, overlooked the first coordinate.

Comment: The second marker does not show up because you are using jQuery call `$('click', …`, but there is no reference to the jQuery library in the header section. If you check in the browser debugger console, you'll notice error message there.